# How to disable accessibility sound in android app?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I want to use custom voice in my app, how can I disable talkback sound?
I have tried this

```
@Override
public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup host, View child, AccessibilityEvent event)

     event.setEventType(event.TYPE_GESTURE_DETECTION_END);

     return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(host, child, event);
}
```

It  works until I open my sliding panel

Comment: I have also tried android:importantForAccessibility="no" , but it has no effect

Comment: Have you tried the volume control buttons?  Seriously though, it is unclear what you define as "TalkBack sounds" or what you're even really wanting to accomplish. Do you mean the spoken feedback?  The little blip earcon sounds?  Touch exploration all together?